# Accessing an SDF SQLServer Mobile file from Java

Tags: java, jdbc, sdf, sql-server-mobile

Here at work we want to access the data inside a `.sdf` file generated in a PDA with `SQLServer Mobile Edition`. We use the `SqlJDBC4` packet for `JDBC` but can't get into the server. We know it's running because we can telnet into it, but from the `Java` code we just get once and again that we can't connect to server.

We use this connection String:

```
String connectionUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=d:\\file.sdf;"+
   "SelectMethod=cursor;Password=test;integratedSecurity=true";
```

Any fellow `stackoverflower` can tell us the right connection string or whatever we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141454/jdbc-driver-for-microsoft-sql-server-cecompact-edition-3-5/1071831#1071831) is from a question about a CE-Database. But maybe it can help you anyway. From my understanding, the problem is similar - getting access to the sdf.

Comment: Thanks for answering this old question. Sadly I can't test it anymore, but I appreciate your effort.