# I need to make a standalone database (preferably SQL Server) for Java code

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, persistence

My Java desktop code uses an SQL server 2008 database as its persistence layer. I want to be able to distribute this code with the database. That is, the java code should sort of "contain the database". Any user of the program should have a local copy of the DB and should be able to use my java code without installing the whole sql server and without doing all the complicated setup (maybe some small exe to install my database would be fine). How do I do this ?

**EDIT**

I want to package my database with my java code. I need some suggestions on how to do it. I am new, so I don't know technical terms related to what i want to do. So, I cannot even search google. What words will i use for searching ? I need ideas on how to do it. The experienced people could guide me.

Comment: You can't do it with SQL Server. Your clients would necessarily need to have SQL Server installed. You can change the database into an embedded one like [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/index.html) and check if the database is installed in client pc, in case isn't then run a script to install the database with base data.

Comment: @Christopher this is a valid question. Also, I don't know how can you write a standalone database for Java code.

Comment: @Christopher - I don't understand why this question is invalid. I want to package my database with my java code. I need some suggestions on how to do it. I am new, so I don't know technical terms related to what i want to do. So, I cannot even search google.

Comment: My bad. This is what I get for not reading in entirety. I'll even out the -1.

Comment: Looks like there may be no JDBC drivers for SQL server Compact. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358318/how-to-use-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-from-java

Comment: an appropriate concluding comment - microsoft still sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find a Java database much easier than Sql Server; SQL server will require more  packaging options.

Some Java DB options include

- [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) comes with the latest version of Java, saves distributing the DB.
- [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) - it has a mixed mode of operation where the initial you connect
  to the DB in embedded mode but a "DB Server" is started so other DB connection can be made
- [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) Old established project.

All 3 offer both Embedded or Server operations. H2's mixed mode can also be very usefull

Comment: Bruce - What are these packaging options ?

Comment: I can not specifically for SQL server, but I have used MsAccess as backend, If you use SQL server does the user have to install SQL Server or will you, If you install SQL server, what if it is already installed ???.  I have found the Pure Java DB's cleaner / easier to use, you just install the DB jar (and possibly start the Server at Computer startup).

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for an [embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database).

There are several databases that you can embed. I don't think this is possible with Microsoft SQL Server. Note that Microsoft SQL Server is a commercial product, so even if you were allowed to distribute it with your application, your customers would need to pay Microsoft for it.

Some databases that can be used as embedded databases in Java are:

- [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)
- [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

Both of the above databases are written in pure Java, which means you don't need operating specific native code; they will work on any platform where Java is available.

Comment: I agree. Embeded databases are perfect to use here.

Comment: Jesper - quick question. I googled embedded SQL server. Can SQL server compact be used instead of the databases you mentioned. I am comfortable with SQL server. Thats why I want to use SQL server.

Comment: @skyscraper no, SQL Server is not an embedded database server. Ifyou do that, you should have to distribute SQL Server compact along with your application.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - If I use SS compact, then will it be almost like using a text file/flat file ? That is, easy and simple with no need for installation, configuration, password etc ?

Comment: Jesper - Thanks for all the answer. JavaDB and H2 seem better though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stick with SQL Server probably you could try with SQL Server Compact. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact and here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx and check whether it suits your needs.

Comment: I am sure, but looks like there are no JDBC and ODBC drivers for SQL server compact.

Comment: @sky scraper maybe this would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141454/jdbc-driver-for-microsoft-sql-server-cecompact-edition-3-5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358318/how-to-use-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-from-java

Comment: rsc - The program does not have any documentation. No support is bad. http://sqlcedatabaseeditor.codeplex.com/ 
btw, what is this DB editor ? Is it a DB ?

Comment: @sky scraper, sorry but I don't know - I've just taken brief look trough SO on your problem about JDBC and SQL Server Compact. I believe that your solution is not a popular one and maybe it would be better to use some embedded db more suitable for using from Java as other pointed out.